# How to add Nextjs cookie based secure authentication?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, authentication, cookies, next.js

I have a small issue. I'm very very very new to Nextjs and I'm trying to learn by making a app. I have managed to make a Login system using next and I have few issues when securing routes. I have successfully added a cookie after successful login. Now I want to validate the cookie whenever user go to a protected route. I have followed below steps using [this](https://dev.to/shubhamverma18/implement-protected-routes-in-nextjs-37ml) tutorial.

1. Made a Higher order component and checked the cookie validation using it.
2. Wrap the protected component using it.

**Below is my HOD.**

```
import { useRouter } from "next/router";
import Cookies from 'js-cookie';

const withAuth = (WrappedComponent) => {
  return (props) => {
    if (typeof window !== "undefined") {
      const Router = useRouter();

      const accessToken = Cookies.get('token');
      if (!accessToken) {
        Router.replace("/");
        return null;
      }
      return <WrappedComponent {...props} />;
    }
    return null;
  };
};

export default withAuth;
```

**And then I have wrapped my component using above HOD.**

```
import React, { Component } from 'react';
import withAuth from '../utils/withAuth';
class Home extends Component {
  render() {
    return (
      <div>
        HOME
      </div>
    );
  }
}

export default withAuth(Home);
```

***ISSUE #1***
Above HOD is showing a console warning saying below.

*Warning: Expected server HTML to contain a matching  in .
div*

Is their anyway I can fix this issue? As per some github answer I have found this can be solved using useEffect. [SOURCE](https://github.com/vercel/next.js/discussions/17443)
Can anyone help me with this?

***ISSUE #2***
In this way, I have to wrap each and every protected component with my HOD. Is this the correct way of doing this or is there any other way to do this better than this?

Thank you so much or your support.

Answer (score 0):

After spending some time. I was able to fix the issue by using below code. Now I just want to know the answer for 2nd issue mentioned above.

***ISSUE #2*** In this way, I have to wrap each and every protected component with my HOD. Is this the correct way of doing this or is there any other way to do this better than this?

Thank you so much or your support.

***Code I use to fix the issue***

```
import Router from 'next/router'
import Cookies from 'js-cookie';
import React, { useState, useEffect } from 'react';

const withAuth = (WrappedComponent) => {
  return (props) => {
    const [isLoggedIn, setLoginStatus] = useState(false);
    useEffect(() => {
      if (typeof window !== "undefined") {
        const accessToken = Cookies.get('token');
        if (accessToken) {
          setLoginStatus(true)
        }
        else {
          Router.push("/")
        }
      }
    }, []);
    if (isLoggedIn) {
      return <WrappedComponent {...props} />;
    } else {
      return null;
    }
  }
};

export default withAuth;
```

Comment: Hi, were you able to solve the issue?